# Better understanding of __str__ usage

Tags: python, function, methods, python-3.x

I'm trying to better understand the proper usage of the `__str__` function.
Let's say I have a very simple class called Character for use in a game that looks like this:

```
class Character(object):
""" A game character. """
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.poisoned = False
    self.strength = random.randrange(10, 20)
    self.max_strength = self.strength
    self.dexterity = random.randrange(10, 20)
    self.max_dexterity = self.dexterity
    self.hit_points = 100
    self.spell_points = 100
    self.weapon = []
    self.spell = []
    self.items = []
    self.aura = []
    self.xp = 0
```

Prior to learning about the `__str__` function, I would have defined a method of the class called `print_stats(self)` that would print the character stats via `Character.print_stats()`. After learning about `__str__` though it seemed like this was a function for defining and displaying the statistics of an object, similar to what I would do with `print_stats(self)`... but in playing with it and learning that the returned value must be a string and not contain integers, it appears my assumption is wrong.

So now my question is what are some examples of good usage of the `__str__`? Would the example I provide benefit from using that function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Printing stats is a fine use of `__str__()`. Simply use string formatting to return a single string value:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ('Name: {name}\n'
        'Poisoned: {poisoned}\n'
        # etc.
    ).format(**self.__dict__)
```

Comment: That's tremendously helpful and taught me something new at the same time. I was unfamiliar with `format(**self.__dict__)` but tested it in my app and it worked like a charm. I've not encountered string formatting like this previously (without using `%s` or `%d`.) Now I'm off to learn more about that snippet of code.

Comment: A word of caution, This doesn't work if the class defines `__slots__`.  That's a definitely a corner case, but it's a tid-bit of information worth knowing in case you ever deal with `__slots__` enabled (restricted?) classes.  One other cool thing that this answer features is the automatic string concatenation that python does :).

Comment: If the class does use `__slots__` then the appropriate snippet is `...).format(name=self.name, poisoned=self.poisoned)`.

Answer (score 3):

`__str__` exists so that you can get a string representation of your object.  Note that the builtin `print` function/statement calls `str` implicitly:

```
print 1
```

is exactly the same as:

```
print str(1)
```

which is the same as:

```
print (1).__str__()
```

because print calls `__str__` implicitly.

---

Now to your class -- The most natural thing to do is if you would have written:

```
print self.foo,self.bar,self.baz
```

You could define `__str__` as:

```
def __str__(self):
    return " ".join(str(x) for x in (self.foo,self.bar,self.baz))
```

Now to print your character's stats, you'd just do:

```
print character  #same as `print str(character)` :)
```

Usually this is a little limited, so there exists string formatting via `.format` (or old "sprintf" style formatting using the `%` operator).

```
def __str__(self):
    return "my {foo} went to the {baz} to buy a {bar}".format(foo=self.foo,
                                                              baz=self.baz,
                                                              bar=self.bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def __str__(self):
  return 'Name: %s, Hit points: %d' % (self.name, self.hit_points)
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value has to be a string, but it can be any string, including one that contains the string representation of integers. A simple example:

```
def __str__(self):
  return "%s (strength: %i)" % (self.name, self.strength)
```

This might return something like `"Arthur (strength: 42)"`.

Answer (score 1):

In basic use cases, `__str__()` and a method like `print_stats()` can pretty safely be interchanged.  However, especially for something like a character in a game, you might want to go with `print_stats()`, as you won't be able to refactor `__str__()` to do something like print the data to the screen (in the context of a graphical desktop or web application), or to take arguments, which could prove useful for things like this.